# Is heat transfer and work done per unit mass path-independent since it can be expressed in terms of intensive thermodynamic properties of a system?

Tags: thermodynamics

The argument given for $du = Tds-Pdv$ being applicable to irreversible processes too (even though it was derived using dQ = TdS for a reversible process, from Clausius' inequality. For a non reversible process it would be dQ<TdS) is that the equation is expressed in terms of intensive thermodynamic properties and so the process path doesn't matter since it's all state functions.

Does this mean that work and heat transfer, per unit mass, are both independent of path? i.e if it's being stated that the Pdv term is state dependant(since it's a combination of intensive thermodynamic properties), isn't that saying that the work per unit mass, which is also Pdv, is path independent

Some additional background: The source of the confusion was the statement made at 4:50 in the lecture [here](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=OagcpBNR4qs&embeds_euri=https%3A%2F%2Fopen.uci.edu%2F&source_ve_path=MjM4NTE&feature=emb_title). Which was that since the relation contains intensive properties only, it's not dependant on path and is always valid. So I thought that if any relation involving only intensive properties is path independant, maybe so should work per unit mass = Pdv (v = specific volume)

This has been clarified in the bottom note in chemomechanics' answer (the accepted answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this mean that work and heat transfer, per unit mass, are both independent of path?

No, it means only that their sum ($u$, the internal energy per unit mass) is path independent.

> isn't that saying that the work per unit mass, which is also Pdv, is path independent

(Edited to correct an error.) No; **just because $T\,ds -P\,dv$ adds up to $u$ and $\frac{Q}{m}+ \frac{W}{m}$ also adds up to $u$ doesn’t mean the components are individually equal!** That’s true only for reversible processes. Furthermore, $P\,dv$ is not path-independent, although $PV$ is.

Make sure not to confuse the external pressure $P_\mathrm{ext}$ in general work expressions ($P_\mathrm{ext}dV$) with the system pressure $P$. They aren’t necessarily the same, and using the same variable for each can cause a lot of confusion.

A possible useful note from our discussion: The "contains state variables" argument is really meant to apply to the definition $U=TS-PV+\sum_i\mu_iN_i$. Each term there is a product of state variables, so each term and the sum are state variables. From that definition, the [Gibbs–Duhem equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs%E2%80%93Duhem_equation), and $dN_i=0$ for closed systems, we get $dU=T\,dS-P\,dV$. This equation combined with references to "containing state variables" could lead one to conclude incorrectly that $P\,dV$, for example, is a state variable.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142512/discussion-on-answer-by-chemomechanics-is-heat-transfer-and-work-done-per-unit-m); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3):

Given that heat is path dependent and heat per unit mass $dq = \frac{dQ}{M}$, heat per unit mass being path independent would imply that the total mass of the system $M$ was path dependent, which is clearly untrue (for a closed system at the very least).

In general the identifications of heat and work (total or per unit mass) with $TdS$ and $-PdV$ hold only for reversible paths and it is only the combination that is path independent.

Comment: The argument given for it being generally applicable is it can be expressed in terms of thermodynamic properties. Similarly, work per unit mass = Pdv. P and specific volume are both thermodynamic properties

Comment: The argument is not that $du$ is a function of state because it can be expressed in term of $Tds$ and $PdV$. Rather it is that as we already know that $du$, $PdV$ and $TdS$ are all functions of state we know that any relation between derived by considering specific (reversible) paths can immediately be generalized to all paths, as the relation is only making statements about the end points of the path, so we can do the computation along any path we choose. It is an argument about the *relationship* not the *quantities*.

Comment: So it's not true that a combination of thermodynamic properties equals a thermodynamic property?

Comment: And you are stating that Pdv is a function of state, but that's sort of what's confusing me. Wouldn't that mean that work is also, and not path dependant

Comment: The relations $dW = PdV$ and $dQ = TdS$ only hold on reversible paths. The argument used for $dU = TdS - PdV$ does not apply because $dW$ and $dQ$ are not functions of state

Comment: Okay. PdV = dW only holds for reversible paths. But then on reversible paths, where it holds, wouldn't it be independant of paths since PdV is a state function (as you stated)

Comment: $PdV$ will be independent of the path but *work done is not $PdV$ in general* and so is allowed to depend on the path

Comment: Work done for a reversible process is not $Pdv$ in general? I don't get this

Comment: For a reversible process, \(PdV = \delta W\) and this means that the *reversible* work *is* path-independent. I think @BySymmetry is simply trying to make clear that \(\delta W\) is path-independent only in the special case of reversible processes. I often try to make this clear by always referring to work in a reversible process as \(\delta W_{rev}\).

Comment: @scmartin How can reversible work be path independant. Picture two points on a pv diagram. Now two quasistatic processes following a straight line and a convex curve. The areas under the curve are not the same.

Comment: @xasthor, I take back my earlier comment. I believe my confusion came from focusing on an isothermal process as the example I considered in my head, which limits the process to a single path. In the more general case of non-isothermal processes, the reversible work can be different as you said. Clearly that has to be true to get work out of reversible cycles.

Answer (score 2):

> The argument given for $du = Tds-Pdv$ being applicable to irreversible
> processes too...is that the equation is expressed in terms of
> thermodynamic properties and so the process path doesn't matter since
> it's all state functions.

The argument is that since internal energy is a state property, any change in internal energy between equilibrium states is the same for any process, reversible or irreversible. That argument does not extend to the individual components of the change in internal energy, namely heat and work, which are individually process dependent.

That said, the equation

$$dU=TdS-Pdv\tag{1}$$

is equivalent to the first law for the case of a reversible process, *provided that* $P$ is the equilibrium pressure of the gas, in which case all the terms are system properties.

> Does this mean that work and heat transfer, per unit mass, are both
> independent of path?

No. It means that the combination of heat and work in the first law are path independent, not that they are individually path independent. Even if heat  and work are both reversible, there can still be an infinite number of reversible paths between two equilibrium states.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But for an irreversible process, $dQ \neq TdS$, it's <TdS. So simply internal energy being a state function, therefore the path doesn't matter argument isn't sufficient I think

Comment: I think I get your point- that between those two states we can construct a quasistatic process. For this the equation will be valid. And dU will be the same for these processes since it's independant of path.

Comment: @xasthor Yes, $dQ\lt TdS$ for an irreversible process. But keep in mind that also $dW\lt Pdv$ for an irreversible process because $P$ is strictly the external pressure not the gas pressure, so that $dU$ will be the same. Generally, less work is done by the system for an irreversible process.

Comment: Got it. What confused me is essentially that the argument that was made to be for this being true for irreversible cases too, was that at 4:50 in this video there was a statement that since the relation contains intensive properties only, it's not dependant on path and is always valid (https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=OagcpBNR4qs&embeds_euri=https%3A%2F%2Fopen.uci.edu%2F&source_ve_path=MjM4NTE&feature=emb_title). Which made me think that if any relation involving only intensive properties is path independant, maybe so should work per unit mass = Pdv (v = specific volume)

Answer (score 1):

The equation dU=TdS-PdV refers to two thermodynamic equilibrium states that are differentially separated from one another.  The path between these two neighboring states can be direct, or it can be very tortuous and irreversible (in terms of the P-, V-, and Q variations), as long as, in the end, the two states are differentially separated and each in thermodynamic equilibrium.

Comment: I guess to put it more clearly: If the Pdv term is a state function, wouldn't that mean that work per unit mass, which also equals Pdv is path independant for reversible processes

Comment: That isn't put clearly to me at all.  I have no idea what you are saying.

Comment: What I mean is, even though $du = Tds- Pdv$ is derived for reversible processes, it's argued that it holds for irreversible processes too, because it's composed of state functions. I.e that TdS and Pdv are state functions. This same point was mentioned in the comments of user BySymmetry's answer, which I'll quote a part of: "Rather it is that as we already know that du, PdVand TdS are all functions of state..."  So what I was wondering is, since for reversible paths Pdv equals dw, that seems to imply that work per unit mass is path-independant

Comment: What I'm saying is that this equation does not apply to every incremental change along an irreversible path.  It only applies to the two  states if 1.  the two states are thermodynamic equilibrium states and 2.  the two thermodynamic equilibrium states are differentially separated.  In other words, realistically, it only applies along a reversible path.

Comment: Got it. That makes sense, but my question was different. Answered now though. Anyway, it was my fault for not articulating it as clearly and highlighting the exact source of confusion from the jump. Which was a particular statement in a YouTube video lecture. Thank you anyway though.

Answer (score 0):

Th equality $dU=TdS -pdV$, or more generally, $$dU=TdS+\sum_k Y_kdX_k \tag{1}\label{1}$$ does not describe a *process*, instead it describes the $U=U(S,X_1, X_2.,,)$ internal energy function and its partial derivatives $T=\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}$ and $Y_k=\frac{\partial U}{\partial X_k}$ as the intensive physical quantities conjugate to the extensive charges $S, X_1,X_2,..$.
The $\eqref{1}$ can be also viewed as being the difference of the internal energies between two infinitesimally close equilibrium states but again it does not describe any *process* between those states. Neither the differential $dU$ or the other differentials $TdS$, $Y_kdX_k$ are state functions because they depend on *two* (here nearby) states and not on one.

It is possible to view the infinitesimal quantities $dS, dX_k$ as being added to the system during a process that started from the sate $\{S, X_k\}$ but to conclude that   the internal energy change is $dU$ per $\eqref{1}$ you need other assumptions, as well, the most important being are

(1) that as the result of such transfer the intensives  $\{T,Y_k\}$ do not change or if they change the result is at least 2nd order negligible and

(2) the extensive variables are conserved, that is if $dX_k^0$ transported (exchanged with the environment) then $dX_k^0=dX_k$ is also the *local* infinitesimal change - very nontrivial assumption

(3) denote by $dS^0$ the transported entropy from the outside, then for a *reversible* process $dS^0=dS$ and for an *irreversible* process $dS^0 < dS$ where $dS$ is the *local* change measured at the equilibrium state $S+dS, \{X_k+dX_k\}$ whose energy now is
$$U(S+dS,X_1+dX_1, X_2+dX_2,..)= U(S,X_1,X_2,..)+TdS+\sum_kY_kdX_k\tag{2}\label{2}.$$
(Note that $dS$ shows up in $\eqref{2}$ and not $dS^0$; the question is how do we know from $dS^0$ what should we have for $dS$ when the two are *not* equal?)